# i have a working query but i need to put a where clause to it

Tags: mysql, sql

this is a working mysql statement

```
update inventory i 
inner join (
    select ingredient_id, sum(amount) amount
    from product_ingredient p
    group by ingredient_id
) p on i.ingredient_id = p.ingredient_id 
set i.amount = i.amount - p.amount
```

these are the tables on my database

ORDER_ITEMS

```
+----------+--------+-----------------+------------+
| order_id |item_id |    item_name    |  quantity  |
+----------+--------+-----------------+------------+
|     1    |   1    |      coffee     |     2      |
|     1    |   2    |      shake      |     2      |
|     2    |   3    |    icecream     |     3      |
+----------+--------+-----------------+------------+
```

PRODUCT_INGREDIENT:

```
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|item_id | ingredient_id   | amount |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|   1    |      123        |  10    |
|   1    |      124        |  15    |
|   1    |      125        |  10    |
|   2    |      124        |  15    |
|   2    |      123        |  10    |
|   2    |      126        |  15    |
|   3    |      124        |  15    |
|   3    |      123        |  10    |
|   3    |      126        |  15    |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

INVENTORY:

```
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|  id    | ingredient_id   | amount |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
|   1    |      123        |  100   |
|   2    |      124        |  100   |
|   3    |      125        |  100   |
|   4    |      126        |  100   |
+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

i need to put a where statement for the sql so that it will only deduct the order_id=1
and not all inside the order_items table

Comment: And what's the problem in doing exactly that? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i'm using this code and everything is fine, even if the product ingredient is duplicated, which is natural. the problem is that it includes order_id=2,3,4 instead of just order_id=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join  ORDER_ITEMS item_id with   subquery p ingredient_id

```
update inventory i 
inner join (
    select ingredient_id, sum(amount) amount
    from product_ingredient p
    group by ingredient_id
) p on i.ingredient_id = p.ingredient_id 
INNER JOIN PRODUCT_INGREDIENT p1 on p1.ingredient_id = p.ingredient_id
INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS o ON o.item_id = p1.item_id
set i.amount = i.amount - p.amount
WHER o.order_id  = 1
```

Based on your comment could be you need  item_id subquery  too

```
  update inventory i 
  inner join ( 
    select item_id, ingredient_id, sum(amount) amount 
    from product_ingredient p 
    group by item_id, ingredient_id 
    ) p on i.ingredient_id = p.ingredient_id 
    INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS o ON o.item_id = p.item_id 
    set i.amount = i.amount - p.amount 
    WHERE o.order_id = 1
```

based  on the result you provided  in comment could be you need the subquery with join between product_ingredient and ORDER_ITEMS for order_id = 1

```
UPDATE inventory i 
INNER  JOIN (
  select p.ingredient_id, sum(p.amount) amount
  from product_ingredient p 
  INNER JOIN  order_items o on o.item_id = p.item_id
  WHERE o.order_id = 1
  GROUP BY p.ingredient_id
) p ON  i.ingredient_id = p.ingredient_id 
SET i.amount = i.amount - p.amount
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202116/discussion-on-answer-by-scaisedge-i-have-a-working-query-but-i-need-to-put-a-whe).